# GWT Deobfuscator Builder ClassCastException

Tags: gwt, builder, classcastexception, requestfactory, deobfuscation

I have a GWT webapp which uses a RequestFactory - the app seems to launch just fine, but as soon as I try to open it in a browser, it blows up with this exception:

```
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet doPost
SEVERE: Unexpected error
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.myapp.console.shared.MyAppRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3126)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.Deobfuscator$Builder.load(Deobfuscator.java:52)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.updateDeobfuscator(ResolverServiceLayer.java:43)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.resolveRequestFactory(ResolverServiceLayer.java:176)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:233)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerCache.java:198)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:215)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
    ....
```

The MyAppRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder class is auto-generated (my class is MyAppRequestFactory), so it's proving very difficult to debug. This didn't used to happen a few weeks ago when I last used this app. What's causing this error and how do I fix it? I'm not a GWT expert, so small words and understandable explanations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a classloader issue, `Deobfuscator.Builder` being loaded from a different (and sibling or child, not parent) classloader than `MyAppRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder`, so the `Deobfuscator.Builder` parent class of `MyAppRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder` is not the same as the `Deobfuscator.Builder` class that tries to load it.

Did you change anything between the time it worked and now?

(note: [GWT 2.6.0's DevMode has a classloader issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=8585), so if you updated to GWT 2.6.0 and don't strictly follow the expected project layout –i.e. some libs missing from your `WEB-INF/lib` and/or your compiled classes not being in `WEB-INF/classes`– then you could run on such issue)